# What title is given to members of the Klingon High Council besides the Chancellor?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, politics

The Klingon High Council is led by an individual called the Chancellor. What title is given to the other members of the Council? "Councillor"? "Lord"? *"Senator"???* I can only recall them being referred to collectively ("the council") or via a verb ("your brother sits on the council") but never addressed directly.

Comment: .....K’ouncilman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on a reading of the original *screenplays* available, the correct terms appears to be **'Councilor'** (with a single 'l').

---

From *[TNG: Redemption.](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/200.txt)*

> **K'TAL:** (booming voice) *Gowron, son of M'Rel, hakt'em.*
>
> Gowron steps forward... **gives all the Councilors a hard look**. Most of them glare back at him, unhappy to be admitting Gowron to their ranks.
>
> [later]
>
> One by one, they step down from the dais and stand behind Toral until only K'tal and the other Councilor  (who voted against him) are left.

and from [TNG: Reunion](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/181.txt)

> **COMPUTER VOICE:** *Council member Duras.*
>
> She reacts. A long beat.
>
> **K'EHLEYR:** *Access biographical files. Subject name: **Councilor Duras.***

Comment: I originally thought this was a typo in the Reunion script, but finding a second example (used twice) in another script written by a different screenwriter sealed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that "Councillor" is the most likely title.  In the *TNG* episode "[Reunion](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Reunion_(episode))," after the computer calls Duras "Council member Duras," Ambassador K'ehleyr refers to him as "**Councillor** Duras."

> K'EHLEYR: By whose order?
>
> COMPUTER: Council member Duras.
>
> K'EHLEYR: Access biographical files. Subject name, **Councillor Duras**.
>
> <sub>[Source](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/181.htm)</sub>

The computer is obviously referring to Duras by position, while K'ehleyr is using his title.

This is backed up by the [script](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/52.htm) for the *Discovery* episode "[The Expanse](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Expanse_(episode))." The introductory scene is set in the Klingon Council chamber and includes a brief conversation between the Chancellor, Duras and an unnamed Councillor:

> CHANCELLOR: Twice, twice he's been captured, and twice he's escaped. Our Magistrate should never have shown him mercy. He should have been executed for his crimes.
>
> **COUNCILLOR**: You had a simple mission, Duras. Locate the rebels that Archer was harbouring and return them to the Empire. But you failed. Archer made a fool of you.
>
> CHANCELLOR: We are offering you a chance to regain your command, and your honour.
>
> DURAS: I will not fail.
>
> <sub>[Source](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/52.htm)</sub>

Comment: Both resources you've quoted are fan-written transcripts.